# LibGDX Box2D: Cannot get Fixture to render

Tags: java, libgdx, jbox2d

I have been recently trying to get back into LibGDX's version of Box2D, and I looked back at a demo I created a few months back, and my code looks fine, and from my Google search results, my code is fine, but for the life of me, I cannot get the `Fixture` to render.

Here is my (Minimalist example) code, and for the life of me, I cannot get it to work *Note: I built a wrapper around the LibGDX `Game` class, should be self-explanatory*:

```
public class TestBox2D extends EGGame {

    int width;
    int height;

    static final Vector2 ZERO_GRAVITY = new Vector2(0f, 0f);

    OrthographicCamera camera;
    World world;
    Body body;
    Box2DDebugRenderer box2dDebugRenderer;
    RayHandler rayHandler;

    ... // Removed Constructor, nothing special here.

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;
        height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
        camera.position.set(width / 2, height / 2, 0);
        camera.update();

        world = new World(ZERO_GRAVITY, true);
        box2dDebugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
        rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera.combined);

        // creating Body
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(width/2, height/2);

        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(1f);

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateGame() {
        world.step(1f / 30f, 6, 2);
        rayHandler.update();
    }

    @Override
    protected void renderGame() {
        box2dDebugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
        rayHandler.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        world.dispose();
    }

    ... // Removed main method, nothing special here.
}
```

Note that `world.getBodyCount();` and `world.getFixtureCount();` both `return 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

The issue was that I was attempting to call `RayHandler#render()` after `Box2DDebugRenderer.render(...)` while the `RayHandler` didn't have any `Light` objects (Adding a `PointLight` allowed it to render), but whatever the reason for it is, it's weird, but calling the `RayHandler#render()` first allows it to work. This might be a bug in `LibGDX` that I will report.

Answer (score 0):

Probable causes of problem.

1. Check if you have called `render` on fixtures in either `RayHandler` class or `Box2DDebugRenderer` class.
2. You have not set the position of the circle shape. It might be lying on the edge and remain out of camera bounds.
3. Check your units. Radius of circle might be relatively so small that it would be invisible, or it might be so large that it might be covering entire screen.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, one of the things mention Tanmay Patil, it resizes body:

Example:

Varible Class:

```
long time = 0;
float testSize = 0;
```

Call in your render method:

```
time += System.nanoTime();
    if (time >= 100000000){
        time = 0;
        testSize += (0.1f); 
        body.getFixtureList().first().getShape().setRadius(testSize);
    }
```

if not notice any change, try the opposite:

```
time += System.nanoTime();
    if (time >= 100000000){
        time = 0;
        testSize -= (0.1f); 
        body.getFixtureList().first().getShape().setRadius(testSize);
    }
```

Edit:

On the other hand, this does not affect the question, but you can call dispose here if you want:

```
    .////////////

    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(1f);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape      = shape;
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    shape.dispose();
}
```